# DynamicMap is not updating with change of variable in Holoviews

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews

I tried the example [here](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Dashboards.html). I can see the visualization but there is no interactivity in JupyterL Lab

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv

from bokeh.sampledata import stocks
from holoviews.operation.timeseries import rolling, rolling_outlier_std

hv.extension('bokeh')

def load_symbol(symbol, variable='adj_close', **kwargs):
    df = pd.DataFrame(getattr(stocks, symbol))
    df['date'] = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    return hv.Curve(df, ('date', 'Date'), variable).opts(framewise=True)

stock_symbols = ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'MSFT']
dmap = hv.DynamicMap(load_symbol, kdims='Symbol').redim.values(Symbol=stock_symbols)

dmap.opts(framewise=True)
```

Output:
[image]

Is there any other setting I have to do in Jupyter lab to make the interaction work?

python - 3.7.6, holoviews - 1.13.1, Bokeh - 1.4.0, Jupyter Lab - 1.2.6

Comment: Have you installed the JupyterLab extension with `jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz`?

Comment: I did now. It's working. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is one place were the kernel model kind of breaks: Though you can associate a virtual environment with a kernel, and virtual environments are basically defined by the packages installed in them, and installing packages (now) automatically enables their associated Jupyter extensions, things are not fully transitive.

Comment: Specifically, enabled extensions are not associated with the kernel, [but with the enabled virtual environment from which a JupyterLab instance is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795639/why-wont-my-holoviews-dynamicmap-update-in-response-to-changes-to-parameter-val#comment121654646_68795639).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my jupyter lab. As @philippjfr pointed out, you check if you have the jupyterlab_pyviz extension and if not run '$ jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz'.
Once it's done you should restart the kernel and maybe reload the site. At least that's what I did and it helped.