# Why won't my HoloViews DynamicMap update in response to changes to parameter values?

Tags: holoviews

Why don't changes to parameter values using the controls result in updates to the HoloViews `DynamicMap` in the MWE below?

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

def plot_mwe(M, m, V_0, scale_axes): 
    scale_factor = np.sqrt(M/m) if scale_axes else 1

    V_max = V_0
    v_max = V_0*np.sqrt(M/m)    
    if not scale_axes:
        x_lim, y_lim = ( max(V_max,v_max)*1.1, )*2
    else:   
        x_lim, y_lim = ( v_max*1.1,  V_max*1.1 )   
   
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

    return hv.Contours( {'x': v_max*np.cos(t), 'y':  V_max*np.sin(t)} ).options(xlim=(-x_lim, x_lim), ylim=(-y_lim, y_lim))

# This works as expected and responds as expected to changes in parameter values
plot_mwe(M=1, m=5, V_0=20, scale_axes=False).opts(width=400, height=400)

dynamic_mwe = hv.DynamicMap(plot_mwe, kdims=['M', 'm', 'V_0', 'scale_axes'])   

# This results in the expected error message shown in the documentation
dynamic_mwe

# Nothing changes in response to changes in the controls
dynamic_mwe.redim.range(M=(1,50),m=(1,50),V_0=(1,100)).redim.values(scale_axes=[True, False])
```

This seems to exactly replicate the example in the "Live parameter exploration" section of the ["Live Data" documentation](https://holoviews.org/getting_started/Live_Data.html) but fails to update. What do I need to do to get my `DynamicMap` to update in response to changes to linked controls?

Comment: I think I see what's going in here. Though `pyviz_comms` is installed in the repo associated with the kernel running the notebook (via. `pip install holoviews[recommended]`, and doing so automatically enables `pyviz_comms` for JuyterLab, it [only does so for the instance of JupyterLab launched from within that activated repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065120/dynamicmap-is-not-updating-with-change-of-variable-in-holoviews?rq=1#comment121654663_61065120). For this to work, it is not enough to use the kernel associated with that repo: JupyterLab must be launched from it.

Answer (score 0):

For figures to update `pyviz_comms` must be installed in the virutalenv that *is active when JupyterLab is launched*. It is not sufficient for `pyviz_comms` to be installed in the virtualenv associated with the kernel being used by the notebook.